# Flask App on Heroku does not stop booting workers

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, gunicorn

I've been trying to deploy my Flask project (Twilio SMS bot) to Heroku, but whenever I deploy the logs show workers being booted non-stop:

```
2021-01-10T18:57:11.525145+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:11 +0000] [20632] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20632
2021-01-10T18:57:11.902427+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:11 +0000] [20633] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20633
2021-01-10T18:57:12.018448+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:12 +0000] [20634] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20634
2021-01-10T18:57:12.475161+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:12 +0000] [20635] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20635
2021-01-10T18:57:12.622354+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:12 +0000] [20636] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20636
2021-01-10T18:57:12.945738+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:12 +0000] [20637] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20637
2021-01-10T18:57:13.301953+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:13 +0000] [20638] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20638
2021-01-10T18:57:13.506961+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:13 +0000] [20639] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20639
2021-01-10T18:57:13.806545+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:13 +0000] [20640] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20640
2021-01-10T18:57:13.912250+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:13 +0000] [20641] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20641
2021-01-10T18:57:14.842376+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:14 +0000] [20644] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20644
2021-01-10T18:57:15.082539+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:15 +0000] [20645] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20645
2021-01-10T18:57:15.245975+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-10 18:57:15 +0000] [20646] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20646
```

And when I try to boot the app, I eventually get Error 12 (timeout) after 30 seconds. Here is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

My slug size is quite large (261 MB), so I'm not sure if it has something to do with this. I've also noticed in the build logs:

```
ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 2.4.0 has requirement wheel~=0.35, but you'll have wheel 0.34.2 which is incompatible.
```

I'm not sure if this would cause an error. Everything runs properly on my local machine. Any suggestions would be appreciated – thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am guessing here, but it could be that your application is not starting on the port number that Heroku is expecting it to (provided by the `PORT` environment variable. When Heroku doesn't detect the app started, it tries again and again until the timeout.

Following the Heroku tutorial for [getting a Python application running on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/python_and_django#heroku-python-quickstart) you should be getting the port number from the environment with something like this:

```py
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
```

before then using it to run the app

```py
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Given that error at the end, you should probably downgrade the version of `wheel` your application uses to match what is available on Heroku too.

Comment: I think the issue was with the wheel, fixing that seems to have fixed the issue. The page now successfully receives post requests from Postman, but when I try to connect it as a webhook via twilio, I am getting error 11200. Could you provide any insight?

Comment: An 11200 from Twilio means Twilio was unable to get a successful response from your endpoint. Are there more details on the error in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger)? Can you see what the failure is in your apps logs (`heroku logs --tail`)?

Comment: It seems I have omitted a small package from the venv which actually processed user input, so when I sent empty post requests via Postman I was seeing results but not when I sent strings via twilio. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @mc2van getting the same issue. How did you fix the wheel issue? Seeing the same warning, then app keeps rebooting

Comment: @josneville Sorry never saw this, had to do with tensorflow / Python versioning though if it's still an issue. I believe I ended up using python3.7.5 and an older version of tensorflow, which worked fine. If you need I can get the specific versions for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with wheel when I was getting a Flask app up and running.  I updated my pip using `sudo apt-get python3-pip` it worked.